# How to resolve [error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'?

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-beam

I am trying to run `sbt publishLocal` on the spotify scio project following **https://spotify.github.io/scio/Getting-Started.html** guide. However, I receive the following error log:

```
PS C:\tools\scio> sbt publishLocal
[info] welcome to sbt 1.4.7 (Amazon.com Inc. Java 1.8.0_265)
[info] loading global plugins from C:\Users\ROCKEM\.sbt\1.0\plugins
[info] loading settings for project scio-build from plugins.sbt ...
[info] loading project definition from C:\tools\scio\project
[warn] There may be incompatibilities among your library dependencies; run 'evicted' to see detailed eviction warnings.
[info] loading settings for project scio from apache.sbt,build.sbt ...
[info] resolving key references (35839 settings) ...
[info] set current project to scio (in build file:/C:/tools/scio/)
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-sql\target\scala-2.13\scio-sql_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-avro\target\scala-2.13\scio-avro_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-core\target\scala-2.13\scio-core_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-macros\target\scala-2.13\scio-macros_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-test\target\scala-2.13\scio-test_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-parquet\target\scala-2.13\scio-parquet_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-tensorflow\target\scala-2.13\scio-tensorflow_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-smb\target\scala-2.13\scio-smb_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-elasticsearch\es7\target\scala-2.13\scio-elasticsearch7_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-redis\target\scala-2.13\scio-redis_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-cassandra\cassandra3\target\scala-2.13\scio-cassandra3_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-jdbc\target\scala-2.13\scio-jdbc_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-google-cloud-platform\target\scala-2.13\scio-google-cloud-platform_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-elasticsearch\es6\target\scala-2.13\scio-elasticsearch6_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-extra\target\scala-2.13\scio-extra_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-macros\target\scala-2.13\api...
[info] Wrote C:\tools\scio\scio-repl\target\scala-2.13\scio-repl_2.13-0.10.0-beta3+6-bb551a41-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-core\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-elasticsearch\es7\target\scala-2.13\api...
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-sql\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-cassandra\cassandra3\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-redis\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-smb\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-avro\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-google-cloud-platform\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] compiling 66 Scala sources and 7 Java sources to C:\tools\scio\scio-google-cloud-platform\target\scala-2.13\classes ...
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-elasticsearch\es6\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-jdbc\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-parquet\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-tensorflow\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[info] Main Scala API documentation to C:\tools\scio\scio-test\target\scala-2.13\api...
[error] invalid setting for -Ybackend-parallelism must be between 1 and 16
[error] bad option: '-Ybackend-parallelism'
[error] Symbol 'type com.spotify.scio.bigquery.syntax.ScioContextSyntax' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'package com.spotify.scio.bigquery.package'.
[error] Make sure that type ScioContextSyntax is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.spotify.scio.bigquery.syntax.
[error] Symbol 'type com.spotify.scio.bigquery.syntax.TableRowSyntax' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'package com.spotify.scio.bigquery.package'.
[error] Make sure that type TableRowSyntax is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.spotify.scio.bigquery.syntax.
[error] Symbol 'type com.spotify.scio.bigquery.syntax.TableReferenceSyntax' is missing from the classpath.
[error] This symbol is required by 'package com.spotify.scio.bigquery.package'.
[error] Make sure that type TableReferenceSyntax is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
[error] A full rebuild may help if 'package.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of com.spotify.scio.bigquery.syntax.
[error] three errors found
[error] Scaladoc generation failed
[error]         at xsbt.Runner.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:50)
[error]         at xsbt.ScaladocBridge.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:21)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:155)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:134)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1(Doc.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1$adapted(Doc.scala:40)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1(RawCompileLike.scala:79)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:72)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4(RawCompileLike.scala:63)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:61)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1(RawCompileLike.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$docTaskSettings$3(Defaults.scala:1978)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] Scaladoc generation failed
[error]         at xsbt.Runner.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:50)
[error]         at xsbt.ScaladocBridge.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:21)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:155)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:134)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1(Doc.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1$adapted(Doc.scala:40)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1(RawCompileLike.scala:79)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:72)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4(RawCompileLike.scala:63)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:61)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1(RawCompileLike.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$docTaskSettings$3(Defaults.scala:1978)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] Scaladoc generation failed
[error]         at xsbt.Runner.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:50)
[error]         at xsbt.ScaladocBridge.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:21)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:155)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:134)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1(Doc.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1$adapted(Doc.scala:40)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1(RawCompileLike.scala:79)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:72)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4(RawCompileLike.scala:63)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:61)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1(RawCompileLike.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$docTaskSettings$3(Defaults.scala:1978)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] Scaladoc generation failed
[error]         at xsbt.Runner.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:50)
[error]         at xsbt.ScaladocBridge.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:21)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:155)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:134)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1(Doc.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1$adapted(Doc.scala:40)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1(RawCompileLike.scala:79)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:72)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4(RawCompileLike.scala:63)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:61)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1(RawCompileLike.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$docTaskSettings$3(Defaults.scala:1978)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] Scaladoc generation failed
[error]         at xsbt.Runner.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:50)
[error]         at xsbt.ScaladocBridge.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:21)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:155)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:134)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1(Doc.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1$adapted(Doc.scala:40)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1(RawCompileLike.scala:79)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:72)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4(RawCompileLike.scala:63)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:61)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1(RawCompileLike.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$docTaskSettings$3(Defaults.scala:1978)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] Scaladoc generation failed
[error]         at xsbt.Runner.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:50)
[error]         at xsbt.ScaladocBridge.run(ScaladocBridge.scala:21)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:155)
[error]         at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.doc(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:134)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1(Doc.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Doc$.$anonfun$scaladoc$1$adapted(Doc.scala:40)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1(RawCompileLike.scala:79)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$prepare$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:72)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4(RawCompileLike.scala:63)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$4$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:61)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1(RawCompileLike.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.RawCompileLike$.$anonfun$cached$1$adapted(RawCompileLike.scala:52)
[error]         at sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$docTaskSettings$3(Defaults.scala:1978)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (scio-avro / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-cassandra3 / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-tensorflow / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-macros / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-core / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-google-cloud-platform / Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] (scio-elasticsearch6 / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-smb / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-redis / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-sql / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-jdbc / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-elasticsearch7 / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-parquet / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-test / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] (scio-google-cloud-platform / Compile / doc) Scaladoc generation failed
[error] Total time: 23 s, completed 05-Feb-2021 10:52:19
```

Build.sbt can be viewed [here](https://github.com/spotify/scio/blob/master/build.sbt).

How can I fix the backend parallelism issue?

Comment: Show your build.sbt

Comment: Basically you have a lot of `Scaladoc generation failed` ,and compilation error on scio-google-cloud-platform. Try to fix those.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok Added reference to the build.sbt file on github.

Comment: @TomerShetah Not sure how to fix them, also these errors show up only after the bad option error from the header.

Comment: Did you do any changes to this repo? Do you have any pending changes? Or did it start when you just cloned it?

Comment: @TomerShetah I simply cloned it.

Comment: This error could be related to this issue, which has now been fixed: https://github.com/spotify/scio/issues/3652#event-4403552969 Perhaps try to clone it again now!